# How do I exclude cache misses when finding slow transactions in new relic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, monitoring, newrelic

We use New Relic RPM (silver) to monitor performance in our rails app.  We've used caching to speed up processing in a lot of our bottlenecks, but now our slow traces are mostly cache misses.  Is there a way for us to exclude time spent fetching things from the cache, so we can see which parts are still slow?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to exclude parts of request execution time from contributing to the total execution time measured with New Relic. You could try lowering the transaction trace threshold until you start to see traces that do exhibit cache hits, so you can get more complete traces for such requests.

You could also look at the Web Transactions page and see how the response time breaks down for all the parts of the request on average. That'll include the contribution from those cache misses, but will give you an idea of other areas to look at, too.

You could also try looking at [Slow SQL statements](http://newrelic.com/docs/features/slow-sql) if your bottleneck appears to be in the database.